# Are bsdutils, coreutils, and busybox all necessary in a Debian install?

Tags: debian, apt

I first installed Debian with a netinst CD without networking, then edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the main repository, then ran `dhclient eth0` to set up networking. Then I installed `less`. This is the only package I have installed after setting up the system.

When I run `dpkg -l | less -S`,  I see `bsdutils`, `busybox`, `coreutils`, all installed. Are they all necessary? If I ran `apt-get --purge remove bsdutils coreutils`, would my system automatically use busybox?

In general, is there a way to tell whether your system would break after removing a package, without actually removing the package?

Comment: If you want a system with BusyBox instead of coreutils, Debian isn't the right distribution. Look for a [tag:small-distribution].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heuristically, here are some things you can look for:

Run `apt-cache show <pkgname>`.

- If the output contains a line that says `Essential: Yes`, chances are you won't even be able to properly remove the package without seriously breaking your system.
- Another good place to look is the `Priority:` line.  If it says `Priority: required`, it's probably an important package that your system needs.

Note that `bsdutils` and `coreutils` are both `Essential: yes` and `Priority: required` on Debian, while `busybox` is not essential and `Priority: optional`.

<sup>AFAIK, `busybox` can not be used as a replacement for `coreutils` on a normal Debian system.  You'd have to jump through quite a few hoops and break many packages to even set that up</sup>